# How to change the icon of an app in the dock in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: icons, dock

I'd like to change the app of the apps on my dock. For example, I'd like to change the Firefox icon to a picture of Kyuubi from Naruto.

Comment: You'll need to edit the /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop file. I can't instruct you how to safely do this, and I wouldn't recommend doing this anyway.

Comment: Probably copying /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop and then editing here is better.

Comment: @N0rbert Good point. +1